# In Java, what purpose do special interfaces like IntFunction, LongFunction serve?

Tags: java, java-8

Similarly, we have different interfaces for `Int*`, `Double*`, `Long*` corresponding to `Function`, `Supplier`, `Predicate`.

It seems to me that the only benefit of using these special interfaces is to have code that is more readable and enforces its clients to use only that specific type as input.

But apart from, am I missing some other use cases?

Comment: @mark-rotteveel Both questions' answers tackle different concepts. Of course it would be better to have question linked to it, but perhaps not as a duplicate?

Comment: That question asks the same question as yours, and the answers address your question. I don't see how they "tackle different concepts".

Comment: I shouldn't have used the word "concept". In any case, no harm as it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The goal of these interfaces is to allow working with primitive types directly. This saves auto-boxing and auto-unboxing, and therefore makes these interfaces (and the related `IntStream`,`LongStream` and `DoubleStream` that depend on them) more efficient.

For example, instead of using a `Function<Integer,R>` that has a method that accepts an `Integer` and produces a result of type `R`, you use an `IntFunction<R>` that has a method that takes an `int` and produces a result of type `R`. If you pass an `int` to that function, you avoid the boxing that would take place if you passed the same `int` to the `Function<Integer,R>`'s method.

Answer (score 4):

IntPredicate takes an `int` as input as opposed to `Predicate<Integer>` that takes an `Integer`, so basically no boxing/unboxing.

Also this introduces extra methods for primitives for example, such `IntStream#sum` for example.